# UI approach for linking child records from the parent view page

Tags: visualforce-component, related-list, relationships, ui

Imagine an app using Account and Contact records. Both can life without another, but on Contact there is a lookup to Account. If you want to link a Contact to an existing Account using Salesforce.com standard UI you have two options:

1. *Adding a "New Contact" on the Contacts related list on the Account view page*
2. *Edit an existing Contact and update its Account Lookup field*

I want to introduce a third option (=build a custom ChildSelector component)

3. *Add multiple existing contacts by clicking "Add existing contacts" from the Account related list*

**My less-technical, more conceptual questions are:**

1. How could the UI after clicking this button look like?
2. Does something like this exist anywhere in Salesforce.com or an AppExchange app?
3. Why doesn't it already exist as part of the Standard UI.

Answer (score 1):

Well one possible solution could be a use of mass contact edit on the contact list view page.

- Go to the contacts page
- Select some contact list filter (All Contacts for example)
- The list with contacts AND checkboxes appears
- Select some contacts (per checkbox click)
- Double click on the Account field
- A popup window appear where you can change an Account and assign it to ALL selected contacts

[image]

Comment: Great idea to do this without any change....On mandatory design requiremennt is to do it from the Account related list and maybe even display the existing Account -> Contact hierarchy to choose from.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Just wondering if you could create an inline visualforce page on the account page layout and put a contacts list view into it: `<apex:ListViews type="Contact" />` Then you could do the same thing just directly on the account page.